# Connecting to Impala from RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, cloudera, impala

I have issues trying to connect to Impala from a Rmd file.

When I run my chunk "by hand" everything is OK. Everything is OK too in a Shiny app or a classic R script.
However when I try to knit my Rmd to HTML I have the following error :

`Erreur : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager] Can't open lib '/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/64/libclouderaimpalaodbc64.so' : file not found`

Here is the code I am using :

```
DBI::dbConnect(
    drv = odbc::odbc(), 
    driver = "Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala",
    host = my_host,
    port = 21050,
    useSASL = 0,
    uid = my_id,
    pwd = my_pwd,
   database = my_database)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `rmarkdown::render("myfile.Rmd")`, it seems to be working.